# HTML/Javascript and Web Services - When should I use a form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-services, twitter-bootstrap

With the modern web technologies there are more and more ways to achieve tasks.  Before we would use Forms to POST data and use it on the Server side code.  But today, when using javascript and web services to use the browser as a client (without server-side code), I am a bit lost when it comes to use forms.  See this example:

I am wondering if I should use a Form to get parameters for my application page.
Basically, I currently have:

```
<div class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Parameter1</label>
        <input class="form-control" id="Parameter1Id" type="text" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button id="RefreshButton" type="button" onclick="RefreshData();" class="btn" >Refresh Values</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
function RefreshData() {
    // this get data method uses AJAX, from jQUery
    GetData($('#Parameter1Id').val(), dataCallBack, errorCallBack);
}

function dataCallBack(data) {
    UpdateUIData(data);
}
```

But I think in this case, for this usage, a Form is not necessary because I could just use objects without putting them in a form.

But also, I have noticed that when not using a form, sometimes the pages reload by itself when a form object changes.

Can you please help me to understand what would be best to do, to build the UI, when using mostly client side code?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to take user input, then *always* use a form.

Consider [progressive enhancement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) with JavaScript to improve the UI, but get something reliable working without a dependancy on JS first.

Comment: I did'nt know about progressive enhancement, this is very nice.  Could you explain why using a form is better?  I just can't see what it changes?

Comment: Because when the JavaScript fails (because a network glitch stopped it from loading, or it reacted badly to the user's ad blocker, or because you have an error in it, or because you use a feature that isn't supported in the user's browser, or because the user has JS turned off or because the user's browser doesn't support JS) then the site will still work.

Comment: Are there other ways to query a web services than Javascript? In this situation, I suppose than the web site would need a "Plan B" to serve the pages already filled with the content.  The web server would query the data itself?

Comment: Yes, that is how you would do it.

Answer (score 1):

Call me old school, but I don't really like the whole idea of "client-side handled" forms.

Use normal forms, unless you absolutely **need** to use javascript (99.9% of the cases, you can use forms without any javascript).

Also, keep in mind that all the validations on the inputs should be done on the server side: way too many times I have seen programmers only validating the user inputs client-side, thus making the software vulnerable to any kind of attack.

If you also feel like checking the user's input via javascript, do that when the "blur" event is triggered on an element; but use this option only to notify the user. Re-check everything on the server.

Last, if you want to submit a form and you want to avoid reloading the whole page, you can use [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_intro.asp), which allows you to make the browser do requests on the background. Also, since you are using jQuery, you may want to know that [jQuery makes AJAX even easier to use](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

Comment: Arguments you are bringing are very good and they help me a lot to understand.  In my situation, my application serves only as a visualisation client (reports/charts).  So there is no real advantage of reloading the entire page because the web service returns all the data.  One thing I would like to understand: when you do a POST of the form, is it possible to catch the parameters when the page reloads (client-side) and to call a web service? I currently do an AJAX call with JQuery without reloading the page.

Comment: I'm not sure if I got the question right, so let me know if I'm wrong: you want to know if you can POST the page, and then, when the page is reloaded, have a javascript client acquire the data that was sent via POST previously, is that correct? you can do that, if you first get the data on the server, and then use some server-side language to generate the page that is being reloaded: you can use some hidden inputs to store the received data and retrieve that data using javascript. Beware of XSS! http://pastebin.com/euNRgemj

Comment: Ok I understand.  The case I have is very special, I have no server code.  Only a Web Service.  I do this on purpose, but I will retain your advices for the future.  So in my situation, AJAX is probably the best (no POSTING).  Thanks for mentioning XSS, this is effectively someting difficult to understand when you are not aware of it!

Answer (score 0):

As far as your "refreshing" problem goes: take a look at AJAX and Jquery. Ajax was made for this very problem!

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: I already use it, I have added a small comment in the code sample to explain.

Comment: Can't comment up there, but you were asking about saving params that you are sending off to the webservices to be used when the page reloads. Look into HTML 5's local storage property to save things on the client side. There are a bunch of libraries out there that will emulate this functionality in older browsers. One of the common libraries that emulates this functionality in older browsers is Modernizr.